# How to ask more when a question already exists by other author?

Tags: discussion, support

I'd like to ask more in this question [What is the "Automatic Maintenance"?](https://superuser.com/questions/495336/what-is-the-automatic-maintenance) in the way that I want to know what *EXACTLY* is done during maintenance (ie a command/script that shows a full list of tasks/processes)

I've read 
https://superuser.com/help/asking and [How to ask a question which is similar to other questions but not exactly similar](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3533/how-to-ask-a-question-which-is-similar-to-other-questions-but-not-exactly-simila) but I can't figure out whether to edit the original question or ask a new one.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd go with a bounty, stating you want more details.

Comment: That seems a proper way but appears to be worth using it only when the answer is really important to me or the community. In this case I'm just curious so I'm not willing to spend reputation points for it :) - Are there other methods?

Comment: If you don't want to spend the reputation, you can of course ask one of the users who answered the question if they have more details, but apart from a bounty that's all I can think of.

Comment: If you look through some of the sources in the answers, you may find what you're looking for. If you don't, you can comment on that answer, or, if it's more specific than the original question, I don't see why it would be considered a duplicate if you clarify in your question, why it's different. I may be wrong though.